# How to block second event C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `Listbox`. Each `Listbox`'s item include some content(text, photo, audio, video) in one big grid.

`Grid` has tap event - it's navigating to page with comments to this `Listbox`'s item.  If `Listbox`'s item has audio - in grid I build a `Textblock' with content "title and artist" and assign event which navigate to page with`audioplayer`.

Near this `Textblock`, I build a Play button. It has an event which just starts music without navigating to `audioplayer`.

And here I have a problem: when I tap to this button - starts event which starts play music(that's OK), and then - starts event of big grid, which navigates me to the page with comments(its bad).

So, a need to block big `Grid`'s event, if I push the button "play".

Comment: Set a flag in the first event, and check it in the second event.  If it's set, clear the flag and cancel the event.

Comment: We might need to see some code here. It sounds like maybe you should be handling the tap event on each ListBox item instead of on the Grid.

Comment: Robert Harvey - so easy, thanks)

Comment: Have you tried `e.Handled = true` in the play buttons event handler?